# XMPP/Jabber server with custom password set up?

Tags: xmpp

I have a service with usernames and passwords already set up that I want to add a Jabber service to.

Is there any open source XMPP servers that I can customise to use my existing usernames and passwords in a Postgres DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp).  You can either write your own extension to support a custom authentication mechanism, or you might be able to manage it with some [simple configuration](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html) (check the section on Authentication Integration).